# Dialogflow IntentHandler not found for intent: myIntent (Dialogflow V2)

Tags: dialogflow-es

Since I upgraded my Dialogflow to use v2 API, I get the following error:

```
Dialogflow IntentHandler not found for intent: myIntent
```

For some reasons, my intent is no longer recognized altough the action name is identical - myIntent.

This is how I'm using my NodeJS (express V4) app to return a response:

```
dialogflowApp.intent('myIntent', (conv, {version}) => {
    conv.close('test');
});
```

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: In V2 API, the action name doesn't matter here. Your intent name must be identical to the string you reference in your code, you need to verify that your intent is also named 'myIntent'.

Comment: What are your imports here, can you include those?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that `myIntent` is spelled the same in Dialogflow and in your NodeJS webhook function, otherwise you'll get this error. This is how I write and access my functions in the webhook:

```
//Function execution
dialogflowApp.intent('myIntent', myIntentFunction); 


//Function definition
function myIntentFunction(conv, {version}){
    conv.close('test');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

V2 Actions SDK uses the **Intent** name instead of the **Action** Name. The Intent name can be found in your request, or directly from DialogFlow intent interface

[image: Screenshot from Actions on Google Documentation]

[DialogFlow V1 to V2 Migration Documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/lib-v1-migration)

Answer (score 1):

In V2 you have to use the intent name instead of the action name. First you define this at the beginning of the index file:

```
'use strict';
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});
```

Then you have to add the code for each intent:

```
app.intent('intentName1', (conv, {parameterName}) => {
     conv.close('Answer text');
});

app.intent('intentName2', (conv, {parameterName}) => {
     conv.ask('Answer text');
});
```

Finally, at the end of the index file, it is necessary to set the DialogflowApp object to handle the HTTPS POST request. Like this:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

In your example:

```
dialogflowApp.intent('myIntent', (conv, {version}) => {
    conv.close('test');
});
```

You should check that you have defined 'dialogflowApp' at the begining of index file:

```
const dialogflowApp = dialogflow({debug: true});
```

Then you have two options:

1. Replace 'myIntent' with the name of the intent
2. Change your intent name to be 'myIntent'

IMPORTANT: You have to make sure that the intent name in dialogflow and that in the code are exactly the same, since it is case sentive.

'version' should be the name of a parameter received from that intent.

Also check that you have this at the end of the index file:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(dialogflowApp);
```

Hope this can help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your intent handler outside your express '/' post route:

```
dialogflowApp.intent('myIntent', (conv, {version}) => {
    conv.close('test');
});
express().post('/', function(req, res)) {
})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [comment](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/issues/118#issuecomment-382662904) on Github, Actions-on-Google V2 does not match on the `action`, but instead matches on the `intent.name`. I have yet to find a smooth way of finding the `name` property of a  Dialogfow `intent`, but I have been able to find it by looking at the Diagnostic info after testing it in the right column.

**Note**: What you named the intent at the top of the screen is the `Display Name`, not the `name`.

*Update*: Part of the `intent.name` can be found in the URL after opening the intent.  The `intent.name` currently is given in the following format:

> projects/<username>/agent/intents/<intent-uuid>

The `intent-uuid` can be found in the last part of the path:

> https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/#/agent/<agent-uuid>/editIntent/<intent-uuid>/

While this is also not ideal either, it can make things a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try also to remove space from the intent name defined in DialogFlow and in your javascript function call. This solve the problem in my case (running in a Azure function)

before :

```
app.intent('Open Car Gate', conv => {
    conv.close('OK, je vais ouvrir le portail en grand !');
});
```

after :

```
app.intent('OpenCarGate', conv => {
    conv.close('OK, je vais ouvrir le portail en grand !');
});
```